# Можно ли подключить второй ноутбук как монитор через соединение TYPE-C (основной ноут) и HDMI (доп ноут)?

Tags: ноутбук, монитор, hdmi

На сколько я понимаю HDMI только передает изображение. А TYPE-C как раз может его принимать.

Comment: Была какая-то прога, которая позволяла даже через интернет второе устройство (планшет, ноубук) использовать как дополнительный монитор

Comment: Да. Я находил такой способ. Пробовал. Но присутствует задержка и не стабильность. Что собственно и не радует.
А соединение через "провод" должно быть ненадёжным. Вот и хочу узнать про него.

Comment: Да, мне тоже интересно, подписался на тему. У меня планшет ещё был дохловатый и из-за этого отображение на нём сильно тормозило

Comment: @CrazyElf, [x2x](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/x2x) и тому подобное. здесь были про это вопросы, но "x2x" — плохая строка для поиска: ни внутренний, ни внешний поиск не хотят её использовать, а подсовывают всякие заменители.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Но это чисто для линукса? Нужно бы уточнить тогда операционку у автора вопроса

Comment: @CrazyElf, нет, к ядру операционной системы программа x2x отношения не имеет. на обоих машинах x-сервер должен работать. а какая уж операционка, и, тем более, ядро в ней — абсолютно фиолетово. я про x2x упомянул потому, что только про эту программу помню (да и использовал только её, когда понадобилась), а в вопросах, где она упоминалась, были приведены и другие примеры, в частности не завязанные именно на x-сервере. // `Нужно бы уточнить тогда операционку` — у москвичей не просят уточнить, про какой именно дефолт-сити они говорят.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin а какая отзывчивость, много ли трафика кушает? Можно ли использовать устройства ввода на слейве?

Comment: @eri, играть будет, наверно, дискомфортно. я подключался с ноутбука к raspberry-pi, на нём vnc-client к удалённому компьютеру. сеть — wifi, скорее всего 802.11b. touchpad, мышь, клавиатура — всё отлично ретранслировалось с ноутбука на raspberry-pi.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin допустим 2 ноута. я набираю сообщение на одном, поворачиваюсь на другой и продолжаю набирать на нем - такое работает?

Comment: @eri, в случае x2x — почему бы и нет? и там и там запущены абсолютно стандартные x-серверы. только благодаря программе x2x устройства ввода с одного из компьютеров «как бы подключаются» дополнительно ещё и к x-серверу другого компьютера. // у меня и клавиатура и мышь, подключенные к raspberry-pi, отлично продолжали работать с запущенным на raspberry-pi x-сервером. // для того, чтобы на ноутбуке «перейти» к экрану монитора, подключенного к raspberry-pi, надо было указатель мыши перевести за край экрана (какой именно — указывается при запуске x2x).

Comment: Теоретически - IP-over-USB и X-сервер на допноуте. Неуказание операционки традиционно воспринимаю как "операционка абсолютно не важна".